# How to connect local mysql(or docker container mysql) from docker container grafana?

Tags: mysql, docker, grafana

I created grafana with a docker container. And I created mysql with docker container. After that, I tried to access grafana and add mysql container via 'data source'. However, the following error occurred. What is the problem?

```
db query error: query failed - please inspect Grafana server log for details
```

[grafana's data sources setting]

Host : 10.0.7.35:3306

And I set bind-address at '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' for 0.0.0.0:3306 in mysql container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in three ways

1. You can run docker with MySQL and expose 3306 (by adding `-p 3306:3306` port and find IP of docker and connect to that port on that IP from the same network
2. Expose MySQL port and then run app docker with `--link name_of_mysql_container:mysql` and then on the app docker just connect to name_of_mysql_container
3. Use Docker composer create
   docker-composer.yml with content similar to:

```
version: '3.2'
    services:
      app:
          build: .
          image: lap
          environment:
             - DB_HOST=mysql
      mysql:
          image: mysql
          ports:
             - "3306:3306"
          environment:
             - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

And then you can use in your app container database connection to host named 'mysql'

Comment: thx for your answer. I just wanna connect mysql(docker container) from grafana(docker container). I already use "ports: - "3306:3306"", but it doesn't work. I add error message in my question, plz check it again. thk u.

Comment: Looks like you are already using composer (as you wrote ports: - 3306 in composer way), so instead of having `Host : 10.0.7.35:3306` try to use `Host: name_of_mysql_container` you can edit the original post and give us full composer file then it will be a bit easier. what you can do is also you can enter docker with grafana and check if there is connectivity (depends on the image you are using you can `docker exec -it grafana bash and then mysql -h mysql -u ..`

Comment: yeah, I tried to `Host : mysql:3306`. but output is same(error). note that, i check ping from mysql container to grafana container, there is no problem with the ping.

Comment: Can you check:
`telnet mysql 3306` or `nc mysql  3306`; do you see if there is connectivity? then if there is means there is a problem with the user and password, try the command `mysql -h mysql -u .. -p..` to check if it is all right. also look at `docker logs grafana` if there is more error to the one you pasted

Comment: ok, i checked grafana container's log. i found this error "Error 1130: Host 'grafana' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server". Do I have to set [database] on grafana.ini?

Comment: This means you shoul add new user:
`CREATE USER 'grafana_user'@'grafana' IDENTIFIED BY 'somehardpassword'; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'grafana_user'@'grafana'; Flush privileges' 

The error you found is because there is no user with host 'grafana' in your mysql user table.

Comment: OMG... I'm ashamed of myself for not being able to solve the simple error that only needs to be created by the user. Thank you!!!